# how to eliminate element(dataframe) from a list in R if contain a specific word

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe. I divide this dataframe in subframes of 6 rows each in a list.
I want if inside in those subframes exist the word "#ERROR" to be deleted all the dataframe( that contain even in one row the specific word) and to receive the list with smaller number of dataframes. Then I am going to convert the list in dataframe again. My problem is that I try different codes and I cannot figure out how to eliminate subdataframe with specific word from the list.

I try the follow

```
a<-dataset 
View(a)
my.list<-split(a, rep(1:119, each = 6)) 

z=lapply(1:length(my.list), function(i) my.list[[i]] != "#ERROR")
```

but what I get they are 119 elements TRUE FALSE. But I want to eliminate those false... anyone please help....

Comment: What if you do `my.list[sapply(1:length(my.list), function(i) my.list[[i]] != "#ERROR")]`?

Comment: Working only for the elements from 1 to 12...from 13th element until 119 returning Null.....by checking the data don't have so many #ERROR

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sapply` as it is will return a vector instead of list like `lapply`.

```
new.list <- my.list[sapply(1:length(my.list), function(i) 
                           all(my.list[[i]] != "#ERROR"))]
```

Or a bit simplified with `Filter` :

```
new.list <- Filter(function(x) all(x != "#ERROR"), my.list)
```

Comment: Seems to work thank you, But something strange. Eliminate also rows with NA. In the begging I accept NA ...and I wanted only rows with  #ERROR to eliminate. Why eliminate also rows with NA? Very strange, maybe exist some explanation please and how to correct?Thanks

Comment: @Adam Yes, because `NA` compared to a string returns `NA` see `NA != 'A'`. Try `Filter(function(x) all(x != "#ERROR" | is.na(x)), my.list)`